# How to fetch the most recent timestamped record for the same id from MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, audit-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

I have an audit table of people and the number of shares they own at a particular timestamp. How do I fetch the most recent record for a given id?

**mysql audit table**

```
id name shares  dateadded 
1  Abc  12      2012-10-06 12:18:21
2  Klm  23      2012-10-06 12:18:21
3  Jim  45      2012-10-06 12:18:21
1  Abc  35      2012-11-06 12:18:21
1  Abc  65      2012-11-17 12:18:21
2  Klm  13      2012-11-06 12:18:21
```

**My desired output :**

```
id name shares  dateadded 
1  Abc  65      2012-11-17 12:18:21
2  Klm  13      2012-11-06 12:18:21
3  Jim  45      2012-10-06 12:18:21
```

I could do something like this :

```
select a.* from audittable a join audittable b 
on a.id = b.id
where a.dateadded > b.dateadded;
```

But that gives me only those most recent records that are repeating. In this case ids 1,2 and not 3. How to get a list of most recent records for all IDs without sub-queries or temp tables?

Comment: Is it a theoretical question? Why not subqueries? The answer by @Michael is probably the fastest way, with proper indexes.

Comment: Not theoretical at all. I was not thinking right! Marc's earlier answer works too select a.*, max(dateadded) from audittable group by id; Isn't it?

Comment: Bill, possibly. I feel my question is well laid out for others to read and understand. The other link is for Oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a subquery, however not subselects (which have a very negative performance hit).

`JOIN` against a subquery which returns the `id` and `MAX(dateadded)` aggregate.  The subquery join is needed to be able to match all the other column values in the row containing the latest timestamp.

```
SELECT
  audittable.id,
  name,
  shares,
  audittable.dateadded
FROM
  audittable
  /* Subquery returns id dateadded grouped by id */
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(dateadded) AS dateadded FROM audittable GROUP BY id
    /* JOIN condition is on both id and dateadded between the two tables */
  ) maxtimestamp ON audittable.id = maxtimestamp.id AND audittable.dateadded = maxtimestamp.dateadded
```

#### [Here is a demonstration on SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aa01/2)

Comment: The op doesn't want subqueries

Comment: Marc, I completely was not thinking. Your earlier solution works just fine. I am oOK with Max and Groupby. As long as I get all the records (repeating or not) just once based on most recent timestamp.

Comment: @Marc This can't be done without a subquery.  The OP may not want subselects, which have a very different performance characteristic than a joined subquery.

Comment: Michael, I would like to know why Marc's earlier solution doesn't work in this case? I thought it just works, no?

Comment: No cause I group by only by id. So you can't have other columns except if you use a subquery like in this answer

Comment: @ThinkCode Because it only returns the id and dateadded, not the other values.  And if you just add the other values into the SELECT list, you won't deterministically get the correct shares back.  MySQL will allow you to do it (which other RDBMS would not), but the results won't always be correct.

Comment: @ThinkCode: Marc's query will not show all columns.

Comment: select a.*, max(dateadded) from audittable group by id; Doesn't it show all columns?

Comment: @ThinkCode It shows all columns, but look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aa01/3  It will list 12 shares for id=1, when it should list 65.  You can't just add other columns into the SELECT list.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much guys for the explanation. Completely overlooked that one.

Answer (score 2):

Without subqueries, you are limited to this

```
SELECT id, MAX(dateAdded)
FROM audittable
GROUP BY id
```

If you want the other columns, you need a subquery like Michael Berkowski's answer

Comment: Oh i see. Well, without a subquery I don't know

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's desired output.